# Right way of putting elements above Nav component? pushes the Nav elements to the side. React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, text, components, react-bootstrap, nav

[image: navbar layout issue]

Hi All, for the life of me, I've been stuck in this dilemma for days. I'm building a new website for my father in law's restaurant & built it in React so I can make the Menu dynamic & bootstrap.
I got the Nav bar JUST how I wanted it except for this last step. I want to add text on the top left which ends up pushing the navbar to the right. I did try to get it hovered in the top left but then it covers my ability to click on "Menu" or "Events". On top of that, I have been unsuccessful in getting text in the top right where I want to put phone numbers. It's like the image blocks the text from stretching to the right, any suggestions?? I couldn't find anything similar to this on google.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  
  <Navbar  variant="light" expand="md" >
    <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href="/" className="d-md-none">
        <img src={logo} height="55px" alt="Mikes Pizzeria" />
      </Navbar.Brand>
        <div id="navContent">Italian Quisine at its Best</div>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mx-auto align-items-end nav-fill w-100">
          <Nav.Link href="/menu">Menu</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/events">Events</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/">Social</Nav.Link>
          <a className="d-none d-md-block"href="/"><img src={logo} alt="Mikes Pizzeria" height="100px"/></a>
          <Nav.Link href="/">VIP Rewards</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/">Order Online</Nav.Link>
          
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
  background-color: rgba(210, 194, 158, 0.7);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#navContent{
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  float:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:20px;
}
```